# Selenium test cases for input text field is not working

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, selenium

I am new to Selenium IDE and I need help in one particular case. I am trying to create a test case for a module in which, when I enter a text it searches in the database and then give results based on the input text. In my case when Im running the recorded test case, it just put the input text but it did not search in the database so, my case gets halted there. I have tried captcha method also, so that I will manually input the text in a popup box but that also doesnt work in this case. Please help me with this issue. Thank you in advance

Comment: So the problem is that the input text isn't submitted?

Comment: @Coretek : No input text is being submitted but its not getting its value from database. My case is that when I click on the text box and start writing, it start matching its value from database and show results in the dropdown, however while using selenium it just put the word it didnt searches it

Comment: Please post some code (Testcase, Database Methode,..)